# Encontrar patrones en listas python

Tags: python, lista, rutas

Tengo un problema algo complejo, por un lado tengo una lista que contiene a su vez listas. Estas contienen numeros enteros que representan posiciones en un mapa:

```
rutas = [[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2],[7,4,8],...[5,6],[0,1,3,4]]
```

a su vez tengo otra lista, que contiene segun su posicion en la lista, las coordenadas de cada uno de esos numeros enteros y un tercer valor que dice si es un punto de entrada, de salida o intermedio.

```
mu = [[12,13,'ent'],[15,-3,'sal'],...[67,0,'med']]
```

Por tanto `mu[0]`, corresponde al numero entero 0 en `rutas`.

Lo que intento hacer pero no consigo es lograr encontrar en `rutas`, secuencias de numeros que vayan desde un 'ent' a un 'sal' y poder plotearlas. Me explico mejor con un ejemplo.

Supongamos que el punto `0 es 'ent'` y que `4 y 3 son 'sal'`, entre otros... 
Quiero poder encontrar en rutas, aquellas secuencias que vayan de 0 a 4 y de 0 a 3, sin importar si 0 es el primer valor en rutas y 4 o 3 el ultimo. Es decir, incluso estando en mitad de la lista. Y ademas si tengo una ruta que es: `[0,1,2,3]` y otra que es `[0,1,2]` que esta ultima cuenta como si perteneciera a `[0,1,2,3]`.

La idea es pues una vez que tengo seleccionadas todas las rutas que van de `ent -> sal` plotear las coordenadas de mu correspondientes.

Si al menos sabeis como enfocarlo o si existe alguna funcion que pueda ayudar.

Comment: Me costó entender, pero lo que pides parece ser un **grafo dirigido**. ¿Estás tratando con listas muy grandes?

Comment: la lista rutas si que es bastante grande, pero las listas dentro de rutas suelen ser cortas, unos 10 valores maximo. De todas forma lo de plotearlas es lo que menos me importa.

Comment: Sería útil que proporcionaras un [mcve] bien definido. Ahora cuesta un poco seguir el ejemplo.

Answer (score 1):

Sin estar *bien definido* como problema, intuyo que lo que intentas hacer es dibujar un grafo sin dibujar dos veces la misma conexión. Que un camino no pase dos veces por la misma arista es lo que se conoce por ["caminio euleriano"](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciclo_euleriano) y puedes encontrar bastante bibliografía sobre cómo afrontar este tipo de problemas, aunque no te extrañe si no encuentras una solución definitiva.

Antes de responder a tu problema, hay algunas dudas y suposiciones:

1. ¿Están todas la rutas bien definidas? Supongo que sí y que **todos las rutas empieza en un nodo `ent` y acaban en uno `sal`**. (En caso contrario, lo primero sería depurar la lista de rutas).
2. Dices que los nodos `ent` y `sal` pueden estar en medio, o sea, pueden hacer de `med`. ¿Es posible que un nodo `ent` aparezca en otra lado como `sal` o viceversa? ¿Es posible que se den ciclos, o sea, una ruta que empieza y acaba en el mismo punto? Voy a suponer que **no hay cierres**, que un punto `ent` siempre aparece como `ent` y uno `sal` siempre como `sal`.
3. ¿Qué pasa con los *solapes*?¿Existe *transitividad*? Supongamos que tenemos dos rutas, `[0,1,2]` y `[1,2,3]`, `0` y `1` son `ent`, y `2` y `3` son `sal`. ¿Hay que tomarlas como dos rutas independientes o formarían una única ruta `[0,1,2,3]`? Por simplicidad, consideraré que **no hay *solapes***, o sea, una ruta se descarta únicamente si está contenida en otra.

Con estas suposiciones basta con comprobar que una ruta no está incluida en otra:

```
def is_included(ruta, rutas):
    n = len(ruta)
    subrutas = (r[i:i+n] for r in rutas for i in range(len(r)-n+1))
    return ruta in subrutas

sel = [ruta for (i,ruta) in enumerate(sorted(rutas, key=len))
      if not is_included(ruta, rutas[i+1:])]
```

Si la lista de rutas es muy grande, es necesario usar alguna estrategia que disminuya el número de comparaciones....